# Radio Button in stateless component in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, stateless

I'm new to react and redux and i want to create component which contain two radio buttons so i write something like this:

import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

```
const renderCashRadioButtons = currentCashSelector => (
  <form onClick={currentCashSelector}>
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="cash-transaction"
      value="Transcation"
      onChange={value => currentCashSelector(value)}
    />
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="cash-transfer"
      value="Transfer"
      onChange={value => currentCashSelector(value)}
    />
  </form>
);


const CashRadioButtons = ({ currentCashSelector }) => (
  <div className="container">
    {renderCashRadioButtons(currentCashSelector)}
  </div>
);

CashRadioButtons.propTypes = {
  currentCashSelector: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};


export default CashRadioButtons;
```

currentCashSelector is a function. When i render this it does not seem to work. The value does not change and i'm not seeing the state to be updated. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I dont think so...i used another radio button component and it worked. But i want to use the default html

Answer (score 1):

1. You probably want your radio buttons to have the same `name`, so that when one is selected, the other is deselected.
2. It looks like your `onChange` functions are expecting the `value`, but they're actually receiving the `event`.
3. You likely have unwanted duplication between the `onChange` on your `form`, and the ones on your radio buttons.

**Possible Solution**

```
  <form onClick={event => currentCashSelector(event.target.value)}>
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="cash-type"
      value="Transaction"
    />
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="cash-type"
      value="Transfer"
    />
  </form>
```